# Twenty Ten Child Theme - Modify Theme Width (940px to 1000px)

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I originally posted this on WordPress Answers but was told it was a CSS issue and should be posted here.

I installed the latest version of WordPress (3.5) and the Twenty Ten theme (1.5) on my web server. I did not modify any settings, everything is the default. All I want my child theme to do is change the theme width from 940px to 1000px. The only file in my child theme is style.css and the only values I changed were the width.

The width adjustments work fine on all desktop browsers but on the iPhone (iOS 6) and iPad (iOS 6) the theme loads with a horizontal scroll bar and it's not possible to zoom all the way out. The horizontal scroll bar problem only effects the home page and not the sample page. The problem is limited to vertical mode only.

Below are screenshots and my style.css code:

My website where I installed the default WordPress with the code below is: www.w242.com

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name: w242
Description: Child theme for the twentyten theme 
Author: w242
Template: twentyten
*/

@import url("../twentyten/style.css");

#access .menu-header,
div.menu,
#colophon,
#branding,
#main,
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px; /* CHANGED 940px ---TO---> 1000px */
}

#access {
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px; /* CHANGED 940px ---TO---> 1000px */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, at style.css line 173, you have an attribute assigned to `div.#wrapper` of `padding: 0px 20px;` which is going to extend the total width of the object to `1040px`.  Since you changed the width of the `#wrapper` child elements to `1000px`, the `padding` style attribute adds another 20px to each side of the inside of itself, extending its size to `1040px`. That's why you're getting the overhang.

Second, these screenshots are from a mobile device.  Are you needing help with formatting for mobile or desktop?  If mobile, the easiest way is to find a mobile theme plugin and modify it as a child theme instead of messing with a 2010 template.  Also, you might want to look into getting away from using pixels as a unit and switch to % or em, or setting up min-width and max-width instead of just width.

Here's an article with some examples. http://www.cssjuice.com/css-liquid-layout-design/

*hint* to change the size of that header image, you're going to need to take a look at the 'functions.php' file.

Comment: I'm aware of the padding, regardless if the wrapper is set to 940px or 1000px. My question is that the width adjustments work fine on all desktop browsers but on the iPhone (iOS 6) and iPad (iOS 6) the theme loads with a horizontal scroll bar and it's not possible to zoom all the way out BUT the theme works fine at 940px. I don't want and shouldn't need any mobile plugins for such a simple adjustment.

Comment: hint to change the size of that header image, you're going to need to take a look at the 'functions.php' file. --- I'm aware, I purposely kept things simple to try and troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Sounds like iOS browsers don't account for padding size when determining the window width.  Google searched the issue and got a few hits back about similar problems.

Check your overflow settings.  If the page won't scroll over, it's probably only rendering to the dimensions of the parent element and hiding the any children elements.

Comment: I doubt that. The Sample Page - 1000px (see the screenshot above) loads correctly in iOS browsers so it has to be accounting for the padding size when determining the window width.

Comment: Have you tried using Adobe Edge Inspect (http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/) - which is free for one device at a time - to see the styles being applied in your iOS6 devices?  Might also be worth looking at the source of your page to see if any viewport meta tags are present in the header. Modern Twenty Twelve might also be a better bet for a responsive base theme.